# Cannot read property 'agency' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have a small problem with my form. I would like to make sure that my agency field is optional, and that it is empty when I do not define a value in it.

```
$scope.search = function () {
  var myform = angular.copy($scope.form);
  myform.agency = myform.agency.id;
  AppService.searchPatient(myform).then(function(response){
    $scope.result = response;
  });
};
```

It's been a while since I'm looking to make this field optional

Comment: `if(myform.agency) { myform.agency = myform.agency.id; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a ternary operator to check if the agency exist

```
$scope.search = function () {
  var myform = angular.copy($scope.form);

  myform.agency = (myform.agency) ? myform.agency.id : "";

  AppService.searchPatient(myform).then(function(response){
    $scope.result = response;
  });
};
```